# axios interceptor not called in mounted() with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am using JWT in my Vue app and need to submit the requisite Authorization header with every AJAX request, using Axios. In my 'main.js' file I set up an interceptor which does this:

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
  if(sessionStorage.getItem('token')) {
    req.headers['Authorization'] = auth.getAuthHeader();
  }
  return req;
});
```

However, in one component I make an AJAX request in mounted(), thus:

```js
mounted() {
  this.salePrep();
}
```

This is the method:

```js
async salePrep(){
  const response = await this.$axios.get(contextPath + "/sale/prep");
  this.$store.commit("setData", response.data);
},
```

For reasons I don't understand, the axios interceptor isn't called for this. Is there something about the mounted() stage which I'm not grasping? Why would this AJAX call be different? Once the component is loaded, all the AJAX calls successfully use the interceptor successfully - i.e., the Authorization header is set. Just not the one in mounted().

EDIT: I have determined that the same is true of calls in 'created()' as well.

Comment: Seems strange. You sure `sessionStorage.getItem('token')` returns something? (maybe try `console.log` to be sure...)

Comment: Tried console.log, the interceptor is not called at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have the ability to comment so here's an answer instead.

Make sure you're creating your interceptors before you're creating the Vue instance in main.js.

Comment: I believe that was the key point, thanks - I was creating my interceptors after creating the Vue instance. Moved that block of code up and it all appears to be working as it should now.